# Get all billing address programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-address

I would like to get all customer shipping address to give shipping selection option in product view page itself.

I created a block to appear inside product view page. And I have below code snippet.

It gives all address including billing address.

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

    $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerData->getId());


    echo '<pre>'; print_r($address); echo '</pre>';
}
```

How to get only shipping address in magento?

Comment: $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress() or  $customerAddressId = Mage::getSingleton(‘customer/session’)->getCustomer()->getDefaultShipping();
if ($customerAddressId){
$address = Mage::getModel(‘customer/address’)->load($customerAddressId);
$address->getData();
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The customer won't always have a default shipping address saved, however if they do you can get it like so :

```
$addressId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultShipping();
if ($addressId){
    $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addressId);
    $address->getData();
}
```

Your just missing the `getDefaultShipping()`

Answer (score 2):

It's Working for me.

The address information is stored within the Mage_Customer_Model_Customer so you should be able to create an instance of it with the customer id.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
```

Then depending on the type of address that you are looking for you should be able to call one of the following functions.

Primary Billing Address: `$model->getPrimaryBillingAddress();`

Primary Shipping Address: `$model->getPrimaryShippingAddress();`

General Address Selection: `$model->getAddressItemById();`

Happy Codding. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$addressesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection');
  $addressesCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
/* for particular address 
$addressesCollection->addFieldToFilter('id','12'); */

foreach ($addressesCollection as $address) {
  echo "<pre>"; 
  print_r($address->getData());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

  foreach ($customerData->getAddresses() as $address) {    
        echo $address->getId();
  }

}
```

Comment: This will give all billing address also. i need only shipping address

Answer (score 0):

@invissible according to Magento, customer only have 1 billing and 1 shipping address as its default address, and all others addresses which is added by customer or admin is set as customer additional address.

As you stated `How to get only shipping address in magento?` in your question, my thought was you only have 1 shipping address only which you get using:

> $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(104);
>
> $default = $customer->getDefaultShipping();

and if you want to show all additional address you can get it using:

> $additional = $customer->getAdditionalAddresses();
>
> foreach($additional as $add){
>
> ```
> Zend_Debug::dump($add->getData(), 'Additional');
> ```
>
> }

Have a look and let me know if you have any query.